# Java Spring Thymeleaf how to use variable outside container

Tags: java, spring, variables, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

How can I either declare a variable and use it outside its container or break the `foreach` loop? This is really bugging me!

The goal is to compare two list and show stuff if the lists match.

The code:

```
<tr th:each="listItem : ${list}">
  <td th:text="${listItem.getTitle()}"></td>
  <td th:text="${listItem.getDescription()}"></td>
  <td>
    <div th:each="listItem2 : ${list2}">
      <div th:if="${listItem.getId()} == ${listItem2.getId()}">
        <div th:with="someVariable={true}">
          // I want to declare variable and use it after the loop OR break the loop here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${someVariable} == true">
      // Show stuff
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Variables defined with `th:with`are only available under the tag. Why you don't do the comparison in your controller?

Comment: Yes I realised that and I know I can make do it in the controller but it feels like a detour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this implementation on the server side, it doesn't make sense use that complex logic with `thymeleaf` it is too difficult to read and maintain, you shouldn't treat that with `thymeleaf`.

So instead of using it like next, you could move this logic to a method, and then call the method using `spEL`.

So, create a method on the top class of the loop which searches that item:

```
package com.example
public class Item {

    int id;
    String title;
    String description;
    //and so on

    //Getters and setters

    public Item getSubItem(List<Item2> list2) {
      for(Item2 item2 :list2){
          if(this.getId() === item2.getId()) {
             return item2;
          }
      }           
       return null;
    }
}
```

Then you just call this method inside the loop to show its info:

```
<tr th:each="listItem : ${list}">
    <td th:text="${listItem.getTitle()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${listItem. getDescription()}"></td>
    <td>
         <div th:if="${listItem.getSubItem(list2)} != null">
           //Show stuff
        </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

In summary, move your logic to java instead of `thymeleaf`.

Comment: Good easy solution ty , too shame thymeleaf doesnt make it easy with loop break or global variables.